# How can I use the shell's process substitution in Perl's system()?

Tags: linux, perl, unix

Why does this line of Perl break?

```
system("paste <\( cut -f2 $file \) $file2 > $fileout");
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is generally caused because Perl is using sh instead of bash to execute the system command.  The quick answer is to include *bash -c* at the start of your command.  A better answer is here:

[How can I use bash syntax in Perl's system()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571368/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-perls-system)