# perl backticks: use bash instead of sh

Tags: perl, backticks

I noticed that when I use backticks in perl the commands are executed using sh, not bash, giving me some problems.

How can I change that behavior so perl will use bash?

PS. The command that I'm trying to run is:

```
paste filename <(cut -d \" \" -f 2 filename2 | grep -v mean) >> filename3
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain the answer is "you don't."

Comment: why? What's your understatement?

Comment: `sh` is universal, `bash` isn't.

Comment: @ether: try `perl -wle'print \`echo foo; ps --forest\`'` to see `sh`.

Comment: BTW, the command I'm trying to run is:
`paste filename <(cut -d \" \" -f 2 filename2 | grep -v mean) >> filename3`

Comment: Why are you even shelling out at all? You can do what you want in pure pure. If you want to run things in the shell, use a shell script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
`bash -c \"your command with args\"`
```

I am fairly sure the argument of -c is interpreted the way bash interprets its command line. The trick is to protect it from `sh` - that's what quotes are for.

Comment: Now I'm getting errors like  -f 1 /tmp/file | grep -v mean) >> /tmp/file2: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
 -f 1 /tmp/file3 | grep -v mean) >> /tmp/file4: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: May be \ aren't needed in my example. Also, don't use  "  inside your command - use  '  .

Comment: SOLVED! The only thing that worked for me was: `\`bash -c 'my_command'\``

Comment: You could also evade quoting problems by using `open my $fh, '-|', qw(bash -c), $cmdline` which is pretty much guaranteed to work exactly as \`$cmdline\` -- but the interface is different.

Comment: Those `\ ` are useless, and would make far more sense to use single quotes than double-quotes.

Comment: @ikegami Sure, single quotes could be used and would be better. But what if they are already used inside `your command with args` ? What if the user needs interpolation inside `-c` argument ?

Comment: @Arkadiy, Re "*But what if they are already used inside*", The whole point of using single-quotes is that you have *less* to escape and that they prevent accidental interpolation, so pointing out that you have to escape single quotes (`'` ⇒ `'\''`) is disingenuous.

Comment: @Arkadiy, Re "*What if the user needs interpolation inside -c argument ?*", That would be a very bad thing to do. Single-quotes actually make it impossible to make this mistake! For example, all three of `bash -c "cat -- $file"`, `bash -c "cat -- \"$file\""` and `bash -c "cat -- '$file'"` are buggy. You should use `bash -c 'cat -- "$0"' "$file"` or `FILE="$file" bash -c 'cat -- "$FILE"'`

Answer (score 9):

The "system shell" is not generally mutable.  See [perldoc -f exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html):

> If there is more than one argument in LIST, or if LIST is an array with more than one value, calls execvp(3) with the arguments in LIST.  If
>   there is only one scalar argument or an array with one element in it, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the
>   entire argument is passed to **the system's command shell for parsing (this is "/bin/sh -c" on Unix platforms, but varies on other platforms).**

If you really need bash to perform a particular task, consider calling it explicitly:

```
my $result = `/usr/bin/bash command arguments`;
```

or even:

```
open my $bash_handle, '| /usr/bin/bash' or die "Cannot open bash: $!";
print $bash_handle 'command arguments';
```

You could also put your bash commands into a .sh file and invoke that directly:

```
my $result = `/usr/bin/bash script.pl`;
```

Comment: I still can't get the expected behavior. The reason I wanted bash is that I run ac command using <(grep ...) and it seems sh does not support it (but bash does). If I run my command as a user, directly from bash it works fine. If I run it from perl in backticks then sh shouts "sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected", if I run it in backticks preceded by /usr/bin/bash I still get the same thing from sh.

Comment: @David: I don't quite understand what command you're trying to run; can you edit that into your question with code formatting?

Answer (score 5):

This example works for me:

```
$ perl -e 'print `/bin/bash -c "echo <(pwd)"`'
/dev/fd/63
```

Answer (score 1):

To deal with running bash and nested quotes, this article provides the best solution: [How can I use bash syntax in Perl's system()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571368/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-perls-system)

```
my @args = ( "bash", "-c", "diff <(ls -l) <(ls -al)" );
system(@args);
```

Comment: Doesn't catch the output though, which is the purpose of using the backticks...

Comment: yeah @DevSolar is right. this solution only works if you don't care about the standard out.

Answer (score 0):

I thought `perl` would honor the `$SHELL` variable, but then it occurred to me that its behavior might actually depend on your system's `exec` implementation. In mine, it seems that `exec`

> will execute the shell
>   (/bin/sh) with the path of the
>   file as its first argument.

You can always do `qw/bash your-command/`, no?

Comment: I still get "sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected". See a comment on the original post for the command I try to run.

Answer (score -1):

Create a perl subroutine:

```
sub bash { return `cat << 'EOF' | /bin/bash\n$_[0]\nEOF\n`; }
```

And use it like below:

```
my $bash_cmd = 'paste filename <(cut -d " " -f 2 filename2 | grep -v mean) >> filename3';
print &bash($bash_cmd);
```

Or use perl here-doc for multi-line commands:

```
$bash_cmd = <<'EOF';
    for (( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )); do
       echo "${i}"
    done
EOF
print &bash($bash_cmd);
```

Answer (score -1):

I like to make some function `btck` (which integrates error checking) and `bash_btck` (which uses bash):

```
use Carp;

sub btck ($)
{
    # Like backticks but the error check and chomp() are integrated

    my $cmd = shift;
    my $result = `$cmd`;
    $? == 0 or confess "backtick command '$cmd' returned non-zero";
    chomp($result);
    return $result;
}

sub bash_btck ($)
{
    # Like backticks but use bash and the error check and chomp() are
    # integrated

    my $cmd = shift;
    my $sqpc = $cmd;   # Single-Quote-Protected Command
    $sqpc =~ s/'/'"'"'/g;
    my $bc = "bash -c '$sqpc'";
    return btck($bc);
}
```

One of the reasons I like to use bash is for safe pipe behavior:

```
sub safe_btck ($)
{
    return bash_btck('set -o pipefail && '.shift);
}
```