# execute shell commands from perl script

Tags: perl, shell

I want to rename *.DIF files to *.SUC files
But the following script is giving "sh: bad substitution" error
I cannot use "rename" becuase my OS is not Linux.

```
$com="for i in *.DIF; do mv \$i \${i/DIF/SUC}; done;";
print $com."\n";
print `$com`;
```

Output :

```
for i in *.DIF; do mv $i ${i/DIF/SUC}; done;
```

`sh: bad substitution`

Comment: while executing "for i in *.DIF; do mv $i ${i/DIF/SUC}; done;" on shell works fine.

Comment: Why don't you just use the perl `rename` function?

Comment: Why does your script have `SUC`, but the output has `DIFFF`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179446/bash-bad-substitution-when-using-code-in-sh-file

Comment: backticks means `run with sh`. But really. Don't do this. Cross contaminating scripting languages is an excellent way to build yourself some horrific bugs and unmaintainable code. Stick to one language - perl or shell, doesn't matter which.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having problems with Perl's `rename`, use [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html), a platform-independent module for moving and copying files.  It is a core module, so it should be already part of your Perl installation.

If the system command works when you enter it in the shell, but not in Perl, the most likely reason is that Perl isn't using the shell you expect.  We would need more information about your system to be sure, though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to shell out for file operations that you can easily do within Perl.

The following renames all of your `.dif` extension files as `.suc`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy qw(move);

move($_, s/dif$/suc/r) for glob('*.dif');
```

Answer (score 0):

be default perl was using sh, instead of bash, which allows {//} 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374082/perl-backticks-use-bash-instead-of-sh) helped.
Finally I used :

```
open my $bash_handle, '| bash' or die "Cannot open bash: $!";
print $bash_handle 'for i in *.SUC; do mv $i ${i/SUC/DIF}; done;';
```