# executing a bash script in perl

Tags: perl, bash

I want to run this command in perl

```
for dir in *; do
 test -d "$dir" && ( find "$dir" -name '*test' | grep -q . || echo "$dir" );
 done
```

I have tried :

```
 system ("for dir in *; do
        test -d "\$dir" && ( find "\$dir" -name '*test' | grep -q . || echo "\$dir" );
        done");
```

but does not work .

Comment: That shell code is easily implemented in Perl. It is wrong to involve several different languages unless it is necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quoting is off.

```
"for dir in *; do
    test -d "\$dir" && ( find "\$dir" -name '*test' | grep -q . || echo "\$dir" );
    done"
```

You have decided to delimit your string with double quotes `"`, but they are included in your string.

Either **escape the other quotes**:

```
"for dir in *; do
    test -d \"\$dir\" && ( find \"\$dir\" -name '*test' | grep -q . || echo \"\$dir\" );
    done"
```

(error prone, ugly)

… or **use another delimiter**: Perl offers you a wide range of possibilities. These quoting syntaxes *interpolate* variables inside: `"…"` and `qq{…}` where you can use any character in `[^\s\w]` as delimiter, and *non-interpolating* syntaxes are: `'…'` and `q{…}` with the same delimiter flexibility as before:

```
qq{for dir in *; do
    test -d "\$dir" && ( find "\$dir" -name '*test' | grep -q . || echo "\$dir" );
    done}
```

The `q` and `qq` constructs can include the delimiter inside the string, if the occurrence is balanced: `q( a ( b ) c )` works.

The third quoting mechanism is a *here-doc*:

```
system( <<END_OF_BASH_SCRIPT );
for dir in *; do
    test -d "\$dir" && ( find "\$dir" -name '*test' | grep -q . || echo "\$dir" );
    done
END_OF_BASH_SCRIPT
```

This is usefull for including longer fragments without worrying about a delimitor. The String is ended by a predefined token that has to appear on a line of its own. If the delimitor declaration is placed in single quotes (`<<'END_OF_SCRIPT'`), no variables will be interpolated:

```
system( <<'END_OF_BASH_SCRIPT' );
for dir in *; do
    test -d "$dir" && ( find "$dir" -name '*test' | grep -q . || echo "$dir" );
    done
END_OF_BASH_SCRIPT
```

Note on the `q{}` and `qq{}` syntax: This is a feature never to be used outside of obfuscation, but it is possible to use a character in `\w` as the delimiter. You have to include a space between the quoting operator `q` or `qq` and the delimiter. This works: `q xabcx` and is equal to `'abc'`.

Comment: I removed the $ , and instead of "" I have used qq as you mentioned,still complains

Comment: @shaq What part of this does not work? Do you get a *syntax error* in Perl, or does it fail at run time or does the shell script fail? What does the error message say? The last code fragment compiles all right with me.

Answer (score 3):

A pure Perl implementation using [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind) module's [`find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind#find) function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

find \&find_directories, '.';

sub find_directories {
    if ( -d && $File::Find::name =~ /test$/ ) {
        print "$File::Find::name\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , but the point is that I want to use shell script command in my Perl:) program

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting the script, try starting a bash instance that runs the script. E.g.

```
system("bash -c 'for dir bla bla bla'");
```

Comment: I want the script to be inside my Perl program

Comment: @shaq: this is a Perl solution

Comment: sorry , I was thinking you mean I have to pass the name of my script to bash ,anyway , I did what you said it is still complaining

Answer (score 0):

`system()` uses your default system shell, which is probably not Bash.  The solution is to [call Bash explicitly with the system() command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571368/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-perls-system).